# How to Get Shell Script to Change File Permissions?

Tags: apache, shell, ubuntu, file-permissions

I have a webpage where users can upload a file.  After the upload, the webpage calls a shell script to move the uploaded file to another location.  I'm certain the "mv" command is failing because of a permissions issue, but I'm uncertain how to overcome this.

First things first.  My webpage runs on an Ubuntu 16.04 server and Apache2 2.4.41.  When the user uploads a file, that file is saved on the server in directory `/var/www/html/uploads`:

```
me@myServer:/var/www/html/uploads$ ls -l
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   761 Feb 21 15:38 UsersUploadedFile.txt
me@myServer:/var/www/html/uploads$
```

I notice that the file is owned by user `www-data`.

Once the file is uploaded, the webpage calls this shell script to move the file to another directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Attempting to move the uploaded file..."
{
        mv /var/www/html/uploads/UsersUploadedFile.txt  /home/me/UsersUploadedFile.txt
} || {
   echo "Gah, failed to move the file!"
}
```

When the file is uploaded, you see this on my webpage:

```
Attempting to move the uploaded file...
Gah, failed to move the file!
```

So the "mv" command is failing.

My first instinct was that this was a permissions issue.  The file-to-be-moved is owned by user `www-data`, as I mentioned before.  The shell script is too:

```
me@myServer:/var/www/html$ ls -l
total 36
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  593 Feb 21 15:53 moveTheFile.sh
me@myServer:/var/www/html$
```

But the directory where I want to file to be moved is owned by user `me`, and I can't change that for other scripting reasons.

What I guess I'd like to do is to is have the shell script change `UsersUploadedFile.txt` 's ownership to user `me`, and then move the file.  But if I insert a `chown` command into the shell script, that command fails, too.

It looks like user www-data is running the apache2 service, therefore also running the shell script...?  I'm not sure.

```
me@myServer:/var/www/html$ ps -ef | grep apache
root      14931      1  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  14934  14931  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  14935  14931  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  14936  14931  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  14937  14931  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  14938  14931  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  14942  14931  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ph9821    15165  14831  0 16:03 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache
me@myServer:/var/www/html$
```

So what might I be doing wrong here?  And how can I get the shell script to change file permissions?  I guess that's what I really need done here.  Thank you.

Comment: This is a permission issue.  www-data cannot write a file in your home directory.  Assuming your home directory is owned by user "me" and group "me", you will have to set permissions on your home directory so your group can write into it (it should already).  Then add user www-data in that group.

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes!  You are completely correct.  I set up a common user group with both "me" and "www-data" in it.  Then, for every directory in my target path, I set the directory's group to the new group.  I also had to "chmod 777" for those directories, too.  My script now works!  You were absolutely right.  If you write this up as a formal answer, I will credit you with the solution.  Thank you for writing!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permission issue. User www-data cannot write a file in your home directory.

Assuming your home directory is owned by user "me" and group "me", you will have to set permissions on your home directory so your group can write into it (it should already). Then add user www-data in that group.

**Important note**

If you put permission 777 on your home directory, then *every user on the system* can write into that directory!  You should put 775 or 770.  Only you and your group should be able to write (and maybe read also, depending on your requirement).  Not important if this is your own machine, critical if this is a machine with many users.

Remember permissions are: user group others.  777 is rwx for all 3.  It can be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks Nic!  Good point on the permissions issue.  Thankfully, this server will be accessible only to me, the users will be interfacing with it via a webpage that I'm building.  But your point is well-taken

Comment: I would add one detail in your script.  Since users will be uploading files, you should add a  `chmod -x FILE` in your script to ensure that uploads are never moved into your home folder with execute permissions.  Then again, keeping them in a self contained, no-exec, filesystem would be best.  But this is opening a can of worms related to securing a web site with file uploads ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, good point!  Will do, thanks so much!  This site rocks...!